# How to redirect that URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I got a rewrite rule (Apache Mod Rewrite):

```
RewriteRule ^(item)/([Gg][Ii][FfMm][0-9][0-9][0-9])/?$ index.php?item=$2
```

that works like this:

```
/item/GIF012/ -> index.php?item=GIF012
```

```
/item/GIM123/ -> index.php?item=GIM123
```

But when url looks like:

```
/item/GIF1/
```

```
/item/GIM12/
```

it simply won't work.
How could I change that rule so those links will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a certain part optional by placing a `?` after it:

```
RewriteRule ^(item)/([Gg][Ii][FfMm][0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)/?$ index.php?item=$2
```

Additionally, the following would be a more compact solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(item)/([Gg][Ii][FfMm][0-9]{1,3})/?$ index.php?item=$2
```

Comment: Yes, 2nd rule is much better. Thanks!